# How to interpret the (possible) relationship between Jacobian and Covariance matrix

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, statistics, derivatives

I'm researching a problem which suggests that progress could be achieved if the Jacobian of a vector function might be in some way considered in the manner of a covariance matrix.

Specifically, and to take the case in $\mathbb{R}^2$, let $f_1 := f_1(x,y)$ and $f_2 := f_2(x,y)$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f_1,f_2: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, the quadratic form of the Jacobian is
$$
\mathbf{J}^{\intercal}\mathbf{J} = 
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\left(\frac{df_1}{dx}\right)^2+\left(\frac{df_2}{dx}\right)^2 & \frac{df_1}{dx}\frac{df_1}{dy}+\frac{df_2}{dx}\frac{df_2}{dy} \\
\frac{df_1}{dx}\frac{df_1}{dy}+\frac{df_2}{dx}\frac{df_2}{dy} & \left(\frac{df_1}{dy}\right)^2+\left(\frac{df_2}{dy}\right)^2
\end{array}
\right].
$$
Suppose we were to compare with the form of covariance matrix $\mathbb{\Sigma}$ expressed as
$$
\mathbb{\Sigma} = 
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\sigma_x^2 & \rho \sigma_x \sigma_y \\
\rho\sigma_x \sigma_y & \sigma_y^2
\end{array}
\right],
$$
it would impose that the correlation coefficient is given by
$$
\rho = \frac{\frac{df_1}{dx}\frac{df_1}{dy}+\frac{df_2}{dx}\frac{df_2}{dy}}
{\sqrt{\left(\frac{df_1}{dx}\right)^2+\left(\frac{df_2}{dx}\right)^2}
\sqrt{\left(\frac{df_1}{dy}\right)^2+\left(\frac{df_2}{dy}\right)^2}
}.
$$
My questions are therefore:

1. Is $\rho$ admissible as a correlation coefficient in the sense that $|\rho| \leq 1$?
2. Are there conditions on $f_1,f_2$ under which (1) is satisfied if not satisfied always?
3. What is the geometric/functional interpretation of the two terms in the denominator?  Clearly they represent norms or 'distances' but is there an intuitive characterisation in terms of $f_1,f_2$?
4. Are there any immediate implications for finding the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{J}^{\intercal}\mathbf{J}$?
5. What branch of mathematics have I happened upon?
6. Any suggestions for reading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some facts which might make this less mysterious.

- The covariance matrix of $n$ random variables can be any $n \times n$ [positive semidefinite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix) matrix.
- If $M$ is any matrix (not necessarily square), then $M^T M$ is a positive semidefinite matrix, and every positive semidefinite matrix can be written in this form.

Now some more specific answers to your questions. Write $f = (f_1, f_2)$.

1. Yes. This follows from the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality). This "correlation coefficient" is the cosine of the angle between the tangent vectors $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$.
2. It's always satisfied, as above.
3. They describe the lengths of the tangent vectors $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ resp. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$, which describe the infinitesimal distance that the vector $f$ travels if $x$ resp. $y$ moves infinitesimally.
4. The eigenvalues of $J^T J$ are the squares of the [singular values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value) of $J$ (this is true for any matrix, not necessarily square). They have the same interpretation singular values always do. For example, the largest singular value is the [operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm). The operator norm of a Jacobian tells us approximately the maximum amount by which a function locally distorts distances.
5. I don't know where this matrix is studied. Typically people are more interested in the eigenvalues of the Jacobian, at least as far as I've seen. The google search for ["singular values of the Jacobian"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22singular+values+of+the+jacobian%22) might be helpful.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful and I'm grateful.  I wonder .... if you happen to have any particular articles in mind regarding the eigenvalues of the Jacobian, I would be most interested in knowing of them.  It is a matter of interest alongside this question.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @Ricky: the google search for "eigenvalues of the Jacobian" might be helpful (https://www.google.com/search?q=%22eigenvalues+of+the+jacobian%22). This naturally comes up when analyzing the behavior of autonomous ODEs $x' = f(x)$ at their fixed points.

Comment: Again, my thanks